# Problems accesing external database inside For iterator

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array called *countriesData* that stores names for various countries, like this:

```
      [Germany,France,Canada,Austria,Switzerland,Spain]
```

I'm trying to iterate over each element in that array, the idea is use each country in a query search over an external API, and then save the length of items in that external API. To put it simple, Im going through each country and counting how many items from that country are stored in an external database.

I have no problem accessing the database outside of the loop, however, I am unable to access it while inside the for iterator.This is my code:

```
    for (var iter = 0; iter < countriesData.length; iter++) {
        var obj = [];
        var country = countriesData[iter]
        var items;
        var itemsCountry = 0;
        $http.get("https://api.discogs.com/database/search?q={?country==" + country + " }&token=zwxZExVZTenjPTKumVeTDVRuniqhQLAxymdzSxUQ").then(function(response) {

            items = response.data.pagination.items;
        })
        var str = "";
        obj.push(countriesData[iter]);
        obj.push(items);
        for (var J = 0; J < myStats.data.length; J++) {

            if (myStats.data[J].country == countriesData[iter]) {
                itemsCountry++;
                str += myStats.data[J].title + ", ";
            }
        }
        obj.push(itemsCountry);
        var str2 = str.substring(0, str.length - 2);
        obj.push(str2);

        newData.push(obj);
        console.log("new obj : " + obj)

    }
```

Basically, I need the var *items* to be updated acording to the length of the response data from *http.get*
This is an example of what I get once I console.log the obj:

```
    France,,2,Thriller, D'eux
```

As you can see, the second element in the array is empty when it should have been an integer representing how many France related items where found in the database...
What is it that Im doing wrong? I get that the database is big and there might not be enough time for it to load. Any idead?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The problem is that the call to `$http.get()` is asynchronous so the rest of your code runs before `items` has a value. You'll need to figure out how to restructure this to work in an asynchronous environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your data call is asynchronous and hasn't completed before you try to push the data to the array.

```
function getCountryData(country) {
    var obj = [];
    var items;
    var itemsCountry = 0;
    $http.get("https://api.discogs.com/database/search?q={?country==" + country + " }&token=zwxZExVZTenjPTKumVeTDVRuniqhQLAxymdzSxUQ").then(function(response) {

        items = response.data.pagination.items;
        var str = "";
        obj.push(country);
        obj.push(items);
        for (var J = 0; J < myStats.data.length; J++) {

            if (myStats.data[J].country == countriesData[iter]) {
                itemsCountry++;
                str += myStats.data[J].title + ", ";
            }
        }
        obj.push(itemsCountry);
        var str2 = str.substring(0, str.length - 2);
        obj.push(str2);

        newData.push(obj);
        console.log("new obj : " + obj)
    })
}

for (var iter = 0; iter < countriesData.length; iter++) {
    var country = countriesData[iter];
    getCountryData(country);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but now the rest of the elements in the obj are not being pushed. This is an example of what I get in the console:   (new obj : ,74267,0,) Only the second element, the size in the external database is correct. What could be causing this error?

Comment: @Duermeduerme I'll edit my response in a few minutes

Comment: @Duermeduerme I have edited my response, see if that helps you

Comment: Thank you so very much! It finally worked :) Have a great day

Comment: Great news! Do you mind accepting this as answer? Have a great day yourself!